# Why 'Arrays class' has overloaded methods

Tags: java, arrays, generics

While going through JavaDocs of Arrays Class. I realized that there are many overloaded methods. For Example,

```
static int binarySearch(byte[] a, byte key)
static int binarySearch(char[] a, char key)
static <T> int binarySearch(T[] a, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

I am not able to understand, why so many overloaded methods are needed, when the last generic method seems to be sufficient.

Even before Generics, method working on `Object` could have solved the problem.

Why is the Arrays class designed with so many over-loaded methods?

Comment: You generally can't cast arrays to one another, e.g. `long[]` cannot be cast to `int[]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put, primitive arrays do not extend `Object[]`, just like primitive types aren't `Object`s. For this reason, a generic method taking `T[]` doesn't work for a primitive array like `int[]`.

Comment: In other words, you can't treat an `int[]` as a `T[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `java.util.Arrays` existed since Java 1.2 , much before the generics were introduced . It had those overloaded methods in them . Secondly , `byte[]` cannot be cast to `Object[]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely:

```
static <T> int binarySearch(T[] a, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Also has a 3rd argument of **`Comparator`** type which is not present in other variant of the `binarySearch` methods.

Answer (score 1):

In brief, it is easier to have the same method name for same functionality. Most of them are designed to work for different primitive type, and the last one is for objects. The generic type T[] does not work for primitive types.